# How to rotate a word2vec onto another word2vec?

Tags: gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

I am training multiple word2vec models with Gensim. Each of the word2vec will have the same parameter and dimension, but trained with slightly different data. Then I want to compare how the change in data affected the vector representation of some words.

But every time I train a model, the vector representation of the same word is wildly different. Their similarity among other words remain similar, but the whole vector space seems to be rotated.

Is there any way I can rotate both of the word2vec representation in such way that same words occupy same position in vector space, or at least they are as close as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That the locations of words vary between runs is to be expected. There's no one 'right' place for words, just mutual arrangements that are good at the training task (predicting words from other nearby words) – and the algorithm involves random initialization, random choices during training, and (usually) multithreaded operation which can change the effective ordering of training examples, and thus final results, even if you were to try to eliminate the randomness by reliance on a deterministically-seeded pseudorandom number generator.

There's a class called `TranslationMatrix` in gensim that implements the learn-a-projection-between-two-spaces method, as used for machine-translation between natural languages in one of the early word2vec papers. It requires you to have some words that you specify should have equivalent vectors – an anchor/reference set – then lets other words find their positions in relation to those. There's a demo of its use in gensim's documentation notebooks:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/translation_matrix.ipynb

But, there are some other techniques you could also consider:

- transform & concatenate the training corpuses instead, to both retain some words that are the same across all corpuses (such as very frequent words), but make other words of interest different per segment. For example, you might leave words like "hot" and "cold" unchanged, but replace words like "tamale" or "skiing" with subcorpus-specific versions, like "tamale(A)", "tamale(B)", "skiing(A)", "skiing(B)". Shuffle all data together for training in a single session, then check the distances/directions between "tamale(A)" and "tamale(B)" - since they were each only trained by their respective subsets of the data. (It's still important to have many 'anchor' words, shared between different sets, to force a correlation on those words, and thus a shared influence/meaning for the varying-words.)
- create a model for all the data, with a single vector per word. Save that model aside. Then, re-load it, and try re-training it with just subsets of the whole data. Check how much words move, when trained on just the segments. (It might again help comparability to hold certain prominent anchor words constant. There's an experimental property in the `model.trainables`, with a name ending `_lockf`, that lets you scale the updates to each word. If you set its values to 0.0, instead of the default 1.0, for certain word slots, those words can't be further updated. So after re-loading the model, you could 'freeze' your reference words, by setting their `_lockf` values to 0.0, so that only other words get updated by the secondary training, *and* they're still bound to have coordinates that make sense with regard to the unmoving anchor words. Read the [source code](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/word2vec.py) to better understand how `_lockf` works.)